# Java jar file not running in Linux terminal

Tags: java, linux, jar, netbeans-7

I am trying to run a `.jar` file in terminal on Linux but gives an error:

```
[root@localhost dist]# java -jar helloworld.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: 
   helloworld.Helloworld (unrecognized class file version)

   at java.lang.VMClassLoader.defineClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
   at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
   at gnu.gcj.runtime.SystemClassLoader.findClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
   at gnu.java.lang.MainThread.run(libgcj.so.7rh).
```

I have checked my version and it is:

```
[root@localhost /]# java --version
java version "1.4.2"
gij (GNU libgcj) version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-51)
```

What is causing this error and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 4):

Try doing the following -

#### First Step:

```
sudo update-java-alternatives -l
```

This to ensure you have JDK6 installed correctly. It should display something like this -

```
java-6-sun 63 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun
```

#### Second Step:

```
sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-6-sun
```

This way both javac and java v6 will be used by default.

#### Update:

Type the following on your terminal -

```
javac -version
```

If you get `javac 1.6.0_10 or later` as the output then you will have to do the following steps. If you dont get the above output, you will have to un-install and re-install java.

#### Steps to do if version shown is 1.6.0_10 or later

1. Create symlink-

   ln -s /usr/local/java /usr/local/jdk1.6.0_10
2. Once that is done, add the following to your `.bashrc` file

   export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.6.0_10
   export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
   export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$JAVA_HOME/lib

Comment: i am using RHEL 5 at first step it is giving error command not found ??

Comment: @SyedRaza Updated the solution to add additional steps.

Comment: @SyedRaza You need to have the `root` access. If you do then you can type `sudo yum install java` on the command line. If you don't have `root` access or administrative privileges then you will have to get in touch with your system administrators.

Comment: i want to install self extraction as it has previously install java version 1.4 so then what would be the steps for installation i have root access too

Comment: 1.4 vaersion is my need for some of my software support so i do not want to uninstall it

Answer (score 0):

You must have compiled with a newer version of the JDK/JRE than the one you're running the jar with. Check the version of the JDK you're using to compile the project in Netbeans, and then check the JDK/JRE version in the console using

```
java -version
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is : "unrecognized class file version" . It means you trying to start jar that was build by incompatible java version.

As I can see, you actually run gcc java. Try to start this jar by original sun/oracle jre

Answer (score 0):

Run the following in your own machine and the actual machine your are trying to deploy:

java -version

If it is different, then you should get the issue.

Note: If you get cannot find command error while running above command, the path variable may not be set correctly. In this case, please go to the dir where jdk/sdk is installed, to bin folder and then run the command.

Answer (score 0):

**You get this error if your versions of javac and java are not the same.**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Runner
(unrecognized class file version)
```

Diagnose the problem this way:

```
$ which java
/usr/bin/java

$ which javac
/home2/ericlesc/bin/jdk1.8.0_40/bin/javac
```

Notice how the javac and the java are not from the same directories?  Those two need to be from the same place, the same version.

To fix it, I added these to my .bash_profile

```
export JAVA_HOME=/home2/ericlesc/bin/jdk1.8.0_40
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$JAVA_HOME/lib
```

Then the error goes away.

You will need yours to point to where you installed java.