# Same Java, but java.lang.ClassFormatError: app.CardNumberHashCalculator

Tags: java

I have 1.6.0_45 JDK and remote server has it too. I checked, class has major 50 version. Why an error occurs?

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: app.CardNumberHashCalculator     (unrecognized class file version)
   at java.lang.VMClassLoader.defineClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
   at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
   at gnu.java.lang.MainThread.run(libgcj.so.7rh)
```

Comment: Both are on the same operating system?

Comment: Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9014992/java-jar-file-not-running-in-linux-terminal

Comment: Your java and javac versions are not the same

Comment: @doublesharp, both linux, but not same.

Comment: @Trobbins, same too.